# Docker: Installing libcurl4-openssl-dev equivalent on Alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile that uses `ruby:2.7.1-alpine` base image. I have a gem that needs `libcurl`, which I am having troubles installing on the Alpine image. I saw a [solution on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/mnyon-grandkru/knowledgebase/issues/43#issuecomment-481333959) associate with the aforementioned gem. But that solution assumes a Debian-based OS, which mentions installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. What I need is the equivalent of this package on Alpine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent package is `curl-dev`. Run:

```
apk add curl-dev
```

Source: See APT <-> APK packages table in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/226).